# Why there are many framework support multiple uploads, but none for multiple downloads?

Tags: java, file-upload, download, httprequest

If I am not wrong, multiple download can only accomplish by zipping file together. What so special about multiple download compare to multiple upload?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Are you referring to multiple files being in a single HTTP request (i.e. a HTTP POST), but only a single file in a HTTP response?

Comment: About multiple upload: I dont want to say that, multiple files is upload using single Http request, however if u look at this showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf, it does seem like multiple files is upload using single http-request. (Just select multiple files to choose upload, even though the upload is sequential, but I only click upload once)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something interesting you may want to read: http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_multiple-files-one-request/

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, conventional browsers expect one file+ContentType in the HTTP response. Although most current browsers may accept a multipart response, YMMV.  From what I can see of the examples, the format is pretty similar (maybe identical) to sending an email with multiple attachments.

[Multipart Responses in HTTP](http://coweb.cc.gatech.edu/cs2340/1252)

Note that the link in the other answer also explains this practice, it's just a little farther down on the page.